# Accessing Class Properties without this Keyword in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, class, this

I'm encountering a confusing situation while working with a JavaScript class. My class properties, which are assigned to specific DOM elements in the constructor, seem to be accessible in the class methods without using the this keyword. This confounds me, as I thought this was necessary for accessing class properties.

Here's the class for context:

```js
class Reminder {
    constructor() {
        this.inputField = document.querySelector('#inputField');
        this.itemList = document.querySelector('#itemList');
        this.msg = document.querySelector('#msg');
        // Other properties...
    }

    loadReminders() {
        // Some code...
        itemList.appendChild(li);
        // Some more code...
    }

    addReminder() {
        if (inputField.value === '') {
            msg.classList.add('error');
            msg.textContent = "No input received";
            msg.style.display = 'block';
            setTimeout(() => msg.style.display = 'none', 1000);
            return false;
        }

        // Other code...
        itemList.appendChild(li);
        inputField.value = '';
        // Rest of the code...
    }

    // Other methods...
}
```

In loadReminders and addReminder methods, I'm able to directly reference inputField, msg, and itemList without any qualifying this keyword, and there is no error.

What's more intriguing is that these properties are not declared globally anywhere else in the script. Is there an implicit binding or scope rule in JavaScript that I'm not aware of that's causing this behavior?

Insights into why these class properties are accessible without the this keyword would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: I have added the full code in here:
https://jsfiddle.net/yashcrest/mzj68edg/2/

Comment: I tried this code, but It's working as expected, I am getting below error

Uncaught ReferenceError: inputField is not defined
    at Reminder.addReminder (test.html:31:18)
    at test.html:37:5


-> Can you please make small programme in jsFiddle and share here.

Comment: The problem can't be reproduced with this much code alone. As far as I know, accessing class properties in such a way is impossible, but guessing won't take us anywhere; you can post all your code to a cloud-based code sharing platform like [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/) or [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) and add a link to your question if deem necessary.

Comment: Hi, I have added the code here:
https://jsfiddle.net/yashcrest/mzj68edg/1/

Answer (score 0):

The `inputField` is not set by your class. It's set by the HTML `id` attribute. You can try it by commenting out this line from the constructor and your `addReminder` can still access `inputField`:

```js
//this.inputField = document.querySelector('#inputField');
```

The `id` attribute set a variable for me in the global scope. I can't find any documentation regarding this behavior so someone may add to this:

```js
console.log(myinput);
myinput.value = "Hello"
console.log(myinput.value);
```

```html
<input id="myinput" />
```

UPDATE: I found it [here](https://css-tricks.com/named-element-ids-can-be-referenced-as-javascript-globals/) which refers to [the specs here: Named access on the Window object](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/nav-history-apis.html#named-access-on-the-window-object)